# Truss rod moved

Tags: acoustic-guitar, truss-rod

My truss rod has moved. What I mean by that is, your basic allen key is shaped like the letter L, and the small part of the letter L goes in the sound hole and makes contact with the truss rod. That’s no longer the case with my guitar. If I put the long end in the sound hole I can reach the end of the truss rod. So my truss rod has moved - it’s receded. Currently, the neck is perfect so I don’t need to use the truss rod, but I’m just wondering why this has happened. It’s a Martin.

Comment: Take it to a tech to have them fix it.

Comment: It might not actually need fixing, but this is certainly a point where being hands-on would help.

Comment: For what it’s worth, on my guitars the nut has always been too far for short part of the Allen key. I doubt it has moved.

Comment: Allen keys are L shaped so either end can be used.

Comment: It definitely moved it used to be accessible with the proper end of Allen key (shorter) end now it’s not.I had it in my hands and felt it shudder and I heard a wood sound and I checked the truss rod and it was No longer accessible with short end. It’s like it was attached to a rubber band and receded. Not knowing the anatomy of the neck I assumed it’s just a solid one piece rod in there so if it receded an inch the other end has to go back an inch somewhere at the other end. or has this thing broken in half? Necks perfect the way it is but resell value is affected. Any one ever experience this

Answer (score 1):

Hm, that might happen. It might be that the routing for the rod has been a bit generous, which might have allowed the truss rod to be pushed in a little bit.

You basically have three options:

- Live with it being less accessible
- Try to get it pulled back out a small bit
- Try to get the routing fixed

The last options would require removing the fretboard to get access, unless we knew exacly where the routing is, in which case we could also drill a small hole from the back of the neck. But it is quite complicated, so unless this is a big problem for you it might just be best to live with it and just get a longer key if you need it.